# How to get Microsoft mail to unblock an IP address?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, hotmail, blacklist

Someone hacked into on of our website's email addresses to send spams since 31 Jan 2019 and we only found out on 4 Feb. Why? Cos we set the password of the email to be 123456. My bad. But we have fixed this and all blacklisting servers are no longer blacklisting us. Except for Microsoft.

When we sent emails to hotmail.com or outlook.com email addresses, we still get "550 5.7.1 Unfortunately, messages from [xx.xxx.xx.103] weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list (S3150)".

We submitted the support request for removal for 4 times at https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportrequestform/8ad563e3-288e-2a61-8122-3ba03d6b8d75 and below is all we got.

> Please note that your ticket number is in the subject line of this
>   mail.
>
> XX.XXX.XX.103
>
> Note: Errors are unlikely, however, if an error is indicated, please
>   resubmit the specific IP or IP range.

Our emails are still being blocked. How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you called Microsoft?

Comment: You need to run an RBL query on the various anti-abuse sites to see where you are blocked, and then find each blocking service's methods for removing the block. This isn't as difficult as it sounds, as each service usually has a straightforward way of getting a blacklist removed. Though it can take some time for the blacklist to be removed.

Comment: You also have to wait. If you've followed the process then you have to wait. You screwed up by allowing your server to be compromised, you have to now deal with the issues caused by that, and those issues include waiting for your request to be processed.

Comment: I checked at http://www.anti-abuse.org and https://www.dnsbl.info/dnsbl-database-check.php and our IP is not blacklisted. We checked this too, https://rblwatcher.com/

Comment: Try this blacklist checker. Very comprehensive. https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx I think the large tech companies are conspiring to eliminate independent and individual communication channels in order to tighten control over the population's ability to communicate with others. For example, my friend said my emails regularly go to his GMail spam folder, even though I am whitelisted, use DKIM and SPF, and am not on any blacklists.

Comment: Tried since day 1. I have all DKIM, SPF, DMARC set and all passed. But still MS is blocking me.